# Unable to upload data to Zookeeper programmatically

Tags: c++, apache-zookeeper

I've installed `Zookeeper` on my `Ubuntu` machine. I'm running it in a cluster mode with three `z1`, `z2` and `z3` instances. When I connect to it with `bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,...` and do `ls /` I see a list of some, say, nodes or data (I'm not sure of terminology). Now what I want is to upload some data programmatically using standard `C++` `client`. To implement this I have a bunch of functions, including `init`, which, I guess, starts a session, `create` function, which internally calls `zoo_acreate` and an empty (for simplicity at this moment) callback function `create_complete`.

The last two mentioned functions look like this:

```
void create(const char * path,
               const char * value) {
    zoo_acreate(zh, 
               path, 
               value, 
               0, 
               &ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, 
               0, 
               create_completion, 
               NULL); 
}

void create_completion (int rc, const char *value, const void *data) {
  // empty at this moment
}
```

However, when I try to use these functions in order to upload some data to zookeeper, I get no result - actually, no errors, but at the same time no data. The way I use these functions is this one:

```
int main(){
    hostPort = (char *)("127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183");
    init(hostPort); // as a result of invoking this function
    // I see in the console some logs, including this message:
    // Initiating client connection, host=127.0.0.1:2181,....
    create("/testworker", "");
    return 0; 
}
```

I thought, this code should create a `/testworker` "folder" inside Zookeeper, however, it does not - `ls /` command shows no changes. One interesting thing I should point out, is that it seems as if my program never calls `create_completion` callback (I checked it with `cout`). So, it may be possible that I need some special flags and some special compiling strings for my program. The way I compile it now is:

```
$ g++ -o test test.cpp -I /...path_to_include_folder/ -L /..path_to_lib_folder/ -lzookeeper_mt
```

**EDIT**

I invastigated the problem a litle bit and found out, that the callback functions are not called at all. For example, the `init` function which starts a session, does not call `main_watcher` callback. Why is that?

**EDIT**

I invastigated it a bit more. It turned out, that `zookeeper_init` (which is called inside my `init` function) returns `0` as a value of `errno` and besides it sets `zh` (which is a zookeeper handler of type `static zhandle_t *`) to some value, so `zh` is not `null` and so, according to [documentation](http://zookeeper.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.2.2plus-pdfsg3/zookeeper_8h_484b8767fa8f150cd15923fabafa90de.html#484b8767fa8f150cd15923fabafa90de), `init` function should be ok (even though it does not trigger callback routine). So it is really strange that I have no error messages in the console and I get no error flags with standard zookeeper methods, but still callbacks and data upload do not work. What is wrong with that and how can I debug it?

**EDIT**

This is a complete source code of my tiny example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "proto.h"
#include "zookeeper.h"
#include "zookeeper_log.h"
#include "recordio.h"
#include "zookeeper.jute.h"
#include "zookeeper_version.h"
#include "errno.h"


using namespace std;

static char *hostPort;
static zhandle_t * zh;
static int connected = 0;
static int expired = 0;
static int server_id;
static struct String_vector * workers = NULL;
static struct String_vector * tasks = NULL;

void create(const char *, const char *);
void create_completion(int, const char *, const void *);

void main_watcher(zhandle_t *zkh,
      int type,
      int state,
      const char *path,
      void* context)
 {
   // cout << "HELLO FROM WATCHER " << endl; // Not printed when I remove comment. Why???
   if(type == ZOO_SESSION_EVENT){
    if(state == ZOO_CONNECTED_STATE){
      connected = 1;
    }
    else if(state == ZOO_AUTH_FAILED_STATE){
      connected = 0;
    }
    else if(state == ZOO_EXPIRED_SESSION_STATE){
      expired = 1;
      connected = 0;
      zookeeper_close(zkh);
    }
  }
}

int init(char* hostPort){
  srand(time(NULL));
  server_id = rand();
  zoo_set_debug_level(ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
  zh = zookeeper_init(hostPort, main_watcher, 15000, 0, 0, 0);
  return errno;
}

void create_completion(int rc, const char *value, const void * data){
  // empty at this moment for simplicity  
}

void create(const char * path, const char * value){
  zoo_acreate(zh, path, value, 0, &ZOO_OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, 0,
      create_completion, NULL);
}



int main(){
 hostPort = (char *)("127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183");
 init(hostPort);
 create("/testworkers", ""); // Do not see this "folder" /testworkers in Zookeeper. Why???
 return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

It really gets me crazy. I spent several days reading a book on `C++` connector to `Zookeeper` and got no result and I've just taken the very first `Python` connector, spent no more than 1.5 minutes and did it. But that is not what I want. I want to see how can I do this trivial thing in `C++` - compile, connect and create. Nothing more.

**EDIT**

I compiled my program with `-DTHREADED` option, but to no avail. Still, `zoo_acreate` does not create anything. It does not produce error messages, it does not produce warnings, it does not return error flags and it does not provide any result. Really strange library.

Comment: zoo_acreate() has a return value. Perhaps it failed and that return code would tell you why.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this code now.

Comment: I checked it. `zoo_acreate` returns `0` in my example.

Comment: @nos. Don't you know why callback functions are not called at all? Should there be some specific tricks to make them work?

Comment: I will start a huuuuge bounty. So, be first to answer to this basic question.

Comment: A teeny-weeny working example will be helpful. I hope there is at least one person in the whole world who knows how to work with `Zookeeper` in `C++`.

Comment: @Jacobian Please, write here how you start ZooKeeper server. And put contents of zoo.cfg file

Comment: @Oleg Gopkolov. I follow pages 32-34 of `ZooKeeper` book by `Flavio Junqueira and Benjameen Reed`, so I do not invent anything. And let me stress it again - I see no trouble when dealing with Zookeeper through `bin/zkCli.sh` or when uploading data to Zookeeper from `Python`. So, I think It does not really matter, since I have the very same `Zookeeper` configuration when I try to connect to it from `Python` and from `C++`. It would be much better if you could share your own cluster `Zookeeper` configuration and your `C++` code, so that we could copy it and make sure that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in the code.

1.In this string `static int server_id;` . Must be `static clientid_t server_id;`

2.And your init func must be

```
int init(char* hostPort)
{
      //srand(time(NULL));
      //server_id = rand();
      zoo_set_debug_level(ZOO_LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
      zh = zookeeper_init(hostPort, main_watcher, 15000, &server_id, 0, 0);
      return errno;
 }
```

Please, pay attention at the `zookeeper_init` and functions `srand(time(NULL));` and `server_id = rand();` must be commented out.

And other thing. See the new version of the **main**. I've added infinite loop.

```
int main()
{
hostPort = (char *)("127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183");
init(hostPort);
create("/testworkers", ""); // Do not see this "folder" /testworkers in Zookeeper. Why???

while(1)
{
     sleep(1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Oleg! I will check it within an hour and if it works, I will be happy to share some karma with you =)

Comment: And can you, please, share where this knowledge comes from? Has `ZooKeeper` book contents become outdated and therefore the only way to figure out how to do all the stuff in C++ is to dive deep into the source code of the Zookeeper library?

Comment: I've just checked it. Unfortunatelly, it makes no difference. Once again I have no error messages, no error flags, but at the same time `zoo_acreate` does not upload any data to `ZooKeeper`

Comment: How can we check that `init` function really established connection?

Comment: Try.............. hostPort = (char *)("127.0.0.1:2181").................For one server.

Comment: even if I connect to Zookeeper with `zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183` ?

Comment: "For one server." Ok. I will check it, but it is not a production mode and Zookeeper should run ideally in a cluster.

Comment: @Jacobian See my answer. I've added something.

Comment: I checked it with `while` loop for one server and it works. Can you explain what was wrong before that? I guess it is something about ephemeral nodes. But how can I switch between ephemeral to "stable" nodes in `C++`?

Comment: By the way, `hostPort = (char *)("127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183");` also works

Comment: Yes, I think it should work. But don't you know how to create persistent data?

Comment: So that not to use the `while` loop. But just to upload data and close the program?

Comment: I think so in that case you must close zookeeper session correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. What I'm asking, is whether it is possible to call `zookeeper_init` or `zoo_acreate` with some arguments so that uploaded data will be persistent and will not be destroyed when the program stops.

Comment: When the program stops all data don't be destroyed. All information is persisted. Check it. All works in my ubuntu. I've checked it. After the our program stops You can invoke `zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2182,127.0.0.1:2183` and then `ls /`and you will see that all data is persisted.

Comment: Well, then I think I should ask another question. If data is persistent and not ephemeral, what is the reason to use an infinite `while` loop?

Comment: "After the our program stops". How can it stop, if it has an infinite loop? Manually? With `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: If it should be done manually, then it is really strange. In Python I could run a script, upload data and forget. I did not have to do something manually. And still can you, please, clarify for what reason do we have to use an infinite loop here? And why `srand(time(NULL));` and `server_id = rand();` were errors?

Comment: You can exclude infinite loop , but in this case you must close session correctly. I think you must call zookeeper_close func before your program have been terminated. `rand()` call returns integer value. But `clientid_t` is not int,but it is struct and you must pass to zookeeper_init function `clientid_t` var, not integer. See prototype of the `zookeeper_init` function.

Comment: "You can exclude infinite loop , but in this case you must close session correctly. I think you must call zookeeper_close func before your program have been terminated." Unfortunatelly, it does not help. I tried to remove the loop and insted added `zookeeper_close(zh)`, but when the program terminates there is no data uploaded.

Comment: I don't have now virtual machine with ubuntu and zookeeper. Tomorrow I will check it.

Comment: BTW. I've just checked it and passed `ZOO_EPHEMERAL` to zoo_acreate and after that I terminated the program manually with Ctrl-C, but in spite of that the created node was not destroyed. So, manual termination like you advised is not the right way to implement the program. And so there is still a lot of issues that remain unsolved.

Comment: "but in spite of that the created node was not destroyed". Well, I checked it again and it was destroyed but with some lag.

Comment: But still the problem with correct termination of the program (without usage of the infinite loop) remains.

Comment: "I've already said. I will check it tomorrow. " Ok. See you later )

Comment: so what happened with the solution without the infinite loop? could you please post it @OlegGopkolov

Answer (score 0):

When creating a ZNode, then you need to state the basic ACL (Access Control List) - here is a basic example of creating a znode :

```
    static zhandle_t *zh;
    static clientid_t myid;
    char buffer[512];    
    struct ACL CREATE_ONLY_ACL[] = {{ZOO_PERM_ALL, ZOO_ANYONE_ID_UNSAFE}};                                        
    struct ACL_vector CREATE_ONLY = {1, CREATE_ONLY_ACL};   


    zh = zookeeper_init("localhost:2181", watcher, 1000, 0, 0, 0);
    int rc = zoo_create(zh,"/xyz","value", 5, &CREATE_ONLY, ZOO_EPHEMERAL, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);             
    if (rc) {
       fprintf(stdout, "Error %d, %s for %s [%d] - could NOT create /xyz \n", rc, zerror(rc), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    }
    else
       cout << "Created /xyc znode" << endl;

    // Watcher function -- basic handling                                                                        
    void watcher(zhandle_t *zzh, int type, int state, const char *path, void* context)                           
    {                                                                                                       
        fprintf(stdout, "Watcher %s state = %s", type2String(type), state2String(state));                        
        if (path && strlen(path) > 0) {                                                                          
            fprintf(stderr, " for path %s", path);                                                               
        }                                                                                                        
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");                                                                                   
        if (type == ZOO_SESSION_EVENT) {                                                                         
            if (state == ZOO_CONNECTED_STATE) {                                                                  
                const clientid_t *id = zoo_client_id(zzh);                                                       
                if (myid.client_id == 0 || myid.client_id != id->client_id) {                                    
                    myid = *id;                                                                                  
                    fprintf(stdout, "Got a new session id: 0x%llx\n", _LL_CAST_ myid.client_id);                 

                }                                                                                                
            } else if (state == ZOO_AUTH_FAILED_STATE) {                                                         
                fprintf(stdout, "Authentication failure. Shutting down...\n");                                   
                zookeeper_close(zzh);                                                                            
                zh=0;                                                                                            
            } else if (state == ZOO_EXPIRED_SESSION_STATE) {                                                     
                fprintf(stdout, "Session expired. Shutting down...\n");                                          
                zookeeper_close(zzh);                                                                            
                zh=0;                                                                                            
            }                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                        
    }
```

this will create a znode - however it will disappear when client closes, because it has ZOO_EPHEMERAL access right, if you want it to exist after your client have disconnected, then you need to change to a different ACL